# My docker doesn't generate the Assets (Mix) (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I created a docker container for a project. However, when I build it, it shows that it generates the js and css files running the command RUN npm run production, but when I check in the browser and inside the container those files aren't there.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM circleci/php:7.3-apache-node-browsers-legacy

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && apt-get install -y zip \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && apt-get install -y git \  
    && apt install -y libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev \ 
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath && docker-php-ext-enable bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmagickwand-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

#ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/lib/apache/runtime
#RUN mkdir -p ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#RUN apt-get install -y apache2

#####################################
# PHPRedis:
#####################################
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# moving the file that manages the host url
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY / /var/www/html

RUN composer self-update
RUN composer install -n --prefer-dist

COPY package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /var/www/html/
  
RUN npm run production --working-dir="/var/www/html"

#RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html

#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html 

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/html/storage

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
#RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the result while building the image:

```
#17 86.87  DONE  Compiled successfully in 82891ms12:34:43 AM
#17 86.87
#17 89.13                                                                                               Asset      Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
#17 89.13                                                                                      /js/backend.js  2.47 MiB       2  [emitted]        [big]  /js/backend
#17 89.13                                                                                  /js/backend.js.map  7.32 MiB       2  [emitted] [dev]         /js/backend
#17 89.13                                                                                     /js/frontend.js  2.07 MiB       3  [emitted]        [big]  /js/frontend
#17 89.13                                                                                 /js/frontend.js.map  6.04 MiB       3  [emitted] [dev]         /js/frontend
#17 89.13                                                                                     /js/manifest.js  1.49 KiB       0  [emitted]               /js/manifest
#17 89.13                                                                                 /js/manifest.js.map  8.06 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]         /js/manifest
#17 89.13                                                                                       /js/vendor.js   325 KiB       1  [emitted]        [big]  /js/vendor
#17 89.13                                                                                   /js/vendor.js.map  1.67 MiB       1  [emitted] [dev]         /js/vendor
#17 89.13                                                                                     css/backend.css   325 KiB       3  [emitted]        [big]  /js/frontend
#17 89.13                                                                                    css/frontend.css   351 KiB       3  [emitted]        [big]  /js/frontend
#17 89.13    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.eot?592643a83b8541edc52063d84c468700   131 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.svg?1d5619cd804367cefe6da2d79289218a   730 KiB          [emitted]        [big]
#17 89.13    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.ttf?513aa607d398efaccc559916c3431403   131 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.woff2?ed311c7a0ade9a75bb3ebf5a7670f31d  74.9 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-brands-400.woff?1a575a4138e5f366474f0e7c5bd614a5  87.9 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.eot?b0e2db3b634d1bc3928e127458d993d8  33.2 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.svg?c5d109be8edd3de0f60eb472bd9ef691   141 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.ttf?766913e6c0088ab8c9f73e18b4127bc4  32.9 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13 fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.woff2?b91d376b8d7646d671cd820950d5f7f1  12.9 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13  fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.woff?d1d7e3b4c219fde0f7376c6facfd7149  15.9 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13     fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.eot?0c6bfc668a72935760178f91327aed3a   198 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13     fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.svg?37bc7099f6f1ba80236164f22e905837   897 KiB          [emitted]        [big]
#17 89.13     fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.ttf?b9625119ce4300f0ef890a8f3234c773   198 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13   fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?d824df7eb2e268626a2dd9a6a741ac4e  76.4 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13    fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff?d745348d289b149026921f197929a893  99.3 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13          fonts/vendor/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/element-icons.ttf?732389ded34cb9c52dd88271f1345af9  54.6 KiB          [emitted]
#17 89.13         fonts/vendor/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/element-icons.woff?535877f50039c0cb49a6196a5b7517cd  27.5 KiB          [emitted]
#17 DONE 89.5s
```